# Is it possible to update a 3.7 eclipse target to use osgi equiknox implementation that supports java 11

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, java-11, equinox

I am looking into updating an eclipse 3.7 application to use java 11.
I have hit a problem on application launch.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20110523 [1]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
```

My understanding of the error is that there is a constraint in the manifest of the plugin preventing it from starting due to unsupported java runtime.

If possible I would like to update my target to a more recent equinox release that supports java 11 (e.g. equinox-SDK-4.18) and also not break the 3.7 target.

Is this possible ?

Thanks,

Comment: The changes for the Java module system, changes to the layout of the JRE, and other changes from Java 9 onwards mean that a lot of things had to be updated in Eclipse. Even Eclipse 4.7 won't run with Java 9. So I think it unlikely that you will be able to just replace a few plug-ins in such an old release. Eclipse plug-ins are not designed in be used in anything other than their target release.

Comment: The reason I thought it might be possible is that Equiknox is available to download as a self contained collection of plugins.

https://download.eclipse.org/equinox/

So, the question is about not just replacing a few plugins but the entire Equiknox implementation.

Is there compatibility information made available somewhere for Equiknox downloads ?

Comment: There are other parts of Eclipse that need updating for Java 9 onwards as well a equinox.